# FlashBuilder 4.6/AIR - Force Menu to be shown in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.6

I am creating an App in FlashBuilder 4.6 using AIR for Android. I make use of the Menu button for additional functionality in my App. In ICS, the menu button is not always shown in every application and others it is. How can I force the Menu button to be shown on phones running ICS? This obviously isn't a problem for Gingerbread, etc. phones as I believe they all have a designated hardware button for the menu. Is there a way using AIR/FB to force the Menu button to be shown?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Are you running your app in Full Screen?  I believe this is set in the app descriptor.

Comment: No, I am not running it in full screen. I did test it in full screen however, and no menu button is shown.

Comment: IF the app was running in full screen; I would not expect the menu button to be shown.  IF not; I would expect it to be there.  But, I haven't had a chance to try that on an ICS unit, yet